# Why does the kernel use macro definitions that expand to the same before and after？

Tags: c, linux-kernel, compilation, macros

I found that some macro definitions in the kernel code expand to the same before and after. Why go through the trouble of defining this macro?

For example, in [/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h#L106) :

```
#define arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed      arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed
#define arch_atomic_add_return_acquire      arch_atomic_add_return_acquire
#define arch_atomic_add_return_release      arch_atomic_add_return_release
#define arch_atomic_add_return              arch_atomic_add_return
```

Comment: Might be because then they can be used for conditional compilation to know if they exist or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A macro that expands to itself has no effect if used in normal code, but it counts as a defined macro for `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, and `#if defined`.

This is useful when you want to define some identifier *not* as a macro, but you also want to be able to conditionally compile code based on whether or not that identifier has been defined.  That's what seems to be going on in your example; `arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h` pairs the macro definitions that you quoted with (macros that expand to) concrete definitions as inline functions:

```
#define ATOMIC_FETCH_OP(name, op)                                       \
static __always_inline int arch_##op##name(int i, atomic_t *v)          \
{                                                                       \
        return __lse_ll_sc_body(op##name, i, v);                        \
}

#define ATOMIC_FETCH_OPS(op)                                            \
        ATOMIC_FETCH_OP(_relaxed, op)                                   \
        ATOMIC_FETCH_OP(_acquire, op)                                   \
        ATOMIC_FETCH_OP(_release, op)                                   \
        ATOMIC_FETCH_OP(        , op)

ATOMIC_FETCH_OPS(atomic_add_return)

#define arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed          arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed
#define arch_atomic_add_return_acquire          arch_atomic_add_return_acquire
#define arch_atomic_add_return_release          arch_atomic_add_return_release
#define arch_atomic_add_return                  arch_atomic_add_return
```

After preprocessing the definition of `arch_atomic_add_return` will be something like

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
int arch_atomic_add_return(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
    return __lse_ll_sc_body(atomic_add_return, i, v);
}
```

Meanwhile, over in [`include/linux/atomic-arch-fallback.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/include/linux/atomic-arch-fallback.h#L195) there is a *conditional* definition of `arch_atomic_add_return`:

```
#ifndef arch_atomic_add_return
static __always_inline int
arch_atomic_add_return(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
    int ret;
    __atomic_pre_full_fence();
    ret = arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed(i, v);
    __atomic_post_full_fence();
    return ret;
}
#define arch_atomic_add_return arch_atomic_add_return
#endif
```

Thus, the point of the `#define` in `arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h` is to tell `include/linux/atomic-arch-fallback.h` "don't define `arch_atomic_add_return`, I already did that".

Comment: Although good to know, the `ATOMIC_FETCH_OP` trick is irrelated to the question here. The macros in the question will not change even if the definitions are not generated by the macro.

Comment: @ouuan Yes, that part I quoted just to demonstrate that there _is_ a non-macro definition of `arch_atomic_add_return` even though it's not immediately visible in the source code. Do you see a way I can make that clearer in the text?

Answer (score 2):

If you search for one of them, you will see that in `include/linux/atomic-arch-fallback.h` there are `#ifndef` checks to use fallback function definitions when the macro is not defined:

```c
#ifndef arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed
#define arch_atomic_add_return_acquire arch_atomic_add_return
#define arch_atomic_add_return_release arch_atomic_add_return
#define arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed arch_atomic_add_return
#else /* arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed */

#ifndef arch_atomic_add_return_acquire
static __always_inline int
arch_atomic_add_return_acquire(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
    int ret = arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed(i, v);
    __atomic_acquire_fence();
    return ret;
}
#define arch_atomic_add_return_acquire arch_atomic_add_return_acquire
#endif

#ifndef arch_atomic_add_return_release
static __always_inline int
arch_atomic_add_return_release(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
    __atomic_release_fence();
    return arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed(i, v);
}
#define arch_atomic_add_return_release arch_atomic_add_return_release
#endif

#ifndef arch_atomic_add_return
static __always_inline int
arch_atomic_add_return(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
    int ret;
    __atomic_pre_full_fence();
    ret = arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed(i, v);
    __atomic_post_full_fence();
    return ret;
}
#define arch_atomic_add_return arch_atomic_add_return
#endif

#endif /* arch_atomic_add_return_relaxed */
```